# How to create jbpm6 web application in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jbpm

I would like to create sample web application with JBPM6. But i am struggling lot to explore the JBPM6.

I tried to run sample application , but it is giving an error.There are no steps to Start the project from Eclipse to JBOSS deploy.
If creating JBPM project , then its not supporting front layer and if select JBPM with maven, then web resources not adding to the project.

Please advise on how to create web application with jbpm6 process in Eclipse ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the following Steps:

- Select `Install New Software` from the Help menu.
- Add the Drools and jBPM update site
  http://downloads.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.0.0.Final/updatesite/.
- Select the JBoss jBPM Core and JBoss Drools Core plugins and click
  "Next >".
- Accept the Terms and Conditions after a review, and Click Finish.
- You might probably get some errors with the installer for unsigned
  content, Click OK.

**Eclipse will restart after that.**

- Then For Your Purpose Click on `File`>>`New`>>`Project`>>`JBPM Project(Maven)`

Comment: Thanks fo reply. After created the workspace there is only java and resources fplders only.but i want to create web application, so how to create dynamic module here. How this web module will communicate to bpmn flow ?

Comment: did you change the perspective?

Comment: Right click on MavenWeb project >> Properties. From the Properties dialog box, select Project Facets >> Modify Project and change the project facet to Java 5.0 or higher. After this step be sure to add the repository to the build path. And you are done.

Comment: Do you mean jbpm perspective j2ee perspective ?

Comment: I would use J2EE Perspective, add JBPM plugins and after the complete application, deploy it using JBOSS AS

Answer (score 2):

Select `"Install New Software ..." from the Help menu`. Add the Drools and jBPM update site http://downloads.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.0.0.Final/updatesite/.

Select the JBoss jBPM Core and JBoss Drools Core plugins and click `"Next >". Click "Next >`" again after reviewing your selecting, accept the terms of the license agreement and click `"Finish"` to download and install the plugins. If you get a warning about installing software that contains unsigned content, click OK. After successful installation, Eclipse should ask you to restart, click Yes.

The plugin should now be installed. To check, check if you can for example see the new jBPM Project wizard: under the `"File" menu, select "New Project` ..." and there you should be able to see "New jBPM Project" under the jBPM category.

Comment: Great , Thanks for reply.To create jbpm web application which jbpm catagory need to be select, because need to create .war file to deploy into jboss server.So which option i need to select to create web application ?

Comment: I think just a maven project."File" menu select "New" and then "Project ..." and under the jBPM category, select "jBPM Project (Maven)".

Comment: Then you just convert it to a webproject under step 3 in this tutorial : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/generate-dynamic-web-project-maven-eclipse-wtp/

Comment: Yes , your correct. But after converted the project , it giving me an error "Data Input has missing or incomplete Data".Since this project is just simple process.

Comment: <ioSpecification>
        <dataInput id="_4_CommentInput" name="Comment" />
        <dataInput id="_4_SkippableInput" name="Skippable" />
        <dataInput id="_4_TaskNameInput" name="TaskName" />
        <dataInput id="_4_ContentInput" name="Content" />
        <dataInput id="_4_GroupIdInput" name="GroupId" />
        <dataInput id="_4_PriorityInput" name="Priority" />

Comment: I guess you have missed something in the conversion or something. Dont know. Just check some tutorial on how to convert from Maven to web application.

Comment: That error is not about the project type.. is an error in your process. So you need to make sure that it is correct. Please use paste bin to copy the errors and the process that you are trying to use